# The last chained promise does not run

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have chained a few methods that I'd like to execute in that specific order.
The second method `deviseLogin()` returns a URL that should be passed on the the next method `redirect(url)`

The first and the second method runs, but I never hear anything from the last `redirect(url)`. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
  getUserToken = (username, password) ->
    console.log "I'm first"
    $http(
      method: "POST"
      url: "/oauth/token"
      params: params
    ).success((data, status, headers, config) ->
      $scope.$storage.token = data.access_token   


  defer = $q.defer()

  $scope.signIn = (data) ->
    defer.promise
      .then( getUserToken($scope.email, $scope.password) )
      .then( deviseLogin() )
      .then( redirect(url) )


  redirect = (url) ->
    console.log "I'm last"
    console.log "will redirect to #{url}"
    $window.location = data.url

  deviseLogin = () ->
    console.log "I'm second"
    $scope.authErrors = []
    authData = { user: { email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password }}
    $http(
      # Perform a regular Devise login
      method: "POST"
      url: "/users/sign_in"
      data: authData
    )
    .success (data) ->
      # I can see the log lines below and data.url is what I expect it to be
      console.log "logged in devise"
      console.log "data.url: #{data.url}"
      data.url
```

Comment: You must pass a *callback function* to `.then()`, not a promise!

Comment: I don't get it. The two first methods are executed but not the last one. Why does that behave differently?

Comment: What does the deviseLogin() fucntion return?

Comment: Maybe it throws a `url is not defined` reference error before it can get called?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos, it returns `data.url`, which I print to console.log on the line above. It's what I expect it to be.

Comment: ah, that is the result of the success() call, which happens *after* deviseLogin() has finished (due to the round-trip of the POST). What does deviseLogin() return?

Comment: *deviseLogin()* returns data.url in it's success function. Should I return anything directly from deviseLogin() E.g. outside the success() callback?  – [edit] Nah, that would not work as data is returned on success. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got the last `.then( redirect(url) )` to kick in. Solved the problem by moving `redirect(url)` to within success() on `deviseLogin()`.

Thanks for all the suggestions and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the functions right away, instead of passing them as callbacks.
The `defer.promise` part also seems unnecessary.

The code should look like this:

```
$scope.signIn = (data) ->
    getUserToken(data.email, data.password)
    .then(deviseLogin)
    .then(redirect)
```